# How to execute Groovy script in PHP

Tags: php, groovy, gvm

I'm trying to execute a command through `shell_exec` in php. But I'm getting an error.

My code :

```
shell_exec('groovy log_analyser1.groovy').
```

But I'm getting this error :

```
sh: groovy: command not found
```

Comment: Have you installed groovy? (otherwise run this from terminal: sudo apt-get install groovy)

Comment: In the terminal its working fine. When i am trying to execute the same command in php. Its not working. I am getting this error. sh: groovy: command not found

Comment: Is groovy in your path? Try using full path for groovy call.

Comment: Yes i have tried to execute that with this command

Comment: /root/.gvm/groovy/current/groovy log_analyser.groovy now permission denied error  the error is /root/.gvm/groovy/current/groovy: Permission denied

Comment: Then you really need to change groovy execution rights so that you dont have to be root to run the command

Comment: yes cfrick. i am running the script as a root user

Comment: Running php (or anything) as root... Probably not the best idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put groovy installation somewhere sane (`/usr/local` or `/opt` or whatever your ops team allows you) and then call groovy with the absolute path.

Since you have currently installed in in your `root` users `~`, other users (like the user your php/httpd runs as) don't have access to it (for good reasons).

Even if you would use the same user as your php/httpd and use GVM there you will have a hard time to make this work properly, since GVM relies on some scripts to run.  So just copy from your GVM files (`~/.gvm/groovy/<version>`) where it's easy for all users to access it.

Comment: groovy: JAVA_HOME not set and cannot find javac to deduce location, please set JAVA_HOME.

Comment: well, it pretty much says it all: set your java environment up properly.  if you can not do this, then spawn the process with that env var set.

Answer (score 0):

Finally got the output. I have moved the groovy directory from /root to /usr/share/. Then gave the groovy path in my php file. Now its working fine. To set java environmental variable.

I have set this `putenv("JAVA_HOME=/usr/share/java/jdk1.7.0_03/");`

```
$result = shell_exec('/usr/share/groovy/2.4.3/bin/groovy log_analyser1.groovy');
```

Thanks Cfrick for the help.
echo $result;